# Why print the wrong result？

Tags: python, hadoop

I am a new guy in python,Today I write a program to get max value pair from some data sets,but the program I wrote did't give me the right answer,the code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

maxsale = 0
oldKey = None
# Loop around the data
# It will be in the format key\tval
# Where key is the store name, val is the sale amount
#
# All the sales for a particular store will be presented,
# then the key will change and we'll be dealing with the next store

for line in sys.stdin:
    data_mapped = line.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data_mapped) != 2:
        # Something has gone wrong. Skip this line.
        continue

    thisKey, thisSale = data_mapped

    if oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
        print oldKey, "\t", maxsale
        oldKey = thisKey;
        oldsale = 0

    oldKey = thisKey
    if maxsale < thisSale:
        maxsale = thisSale
if oldKey != None:
    print oldKey, "\t", maxsale
```

the data sets is:

```
Anchorage       298.86
Anchorage       6.38
Aurora  34.1
Aurora  10.6
Aurora  55.7
Austin  327.75
Austin  379.6
Austin  469.63
Austin  11.6
```

The result is:

```
Anchorage   6.38
Aurora  34.1
Austin  469.63
```

Can anyone help me deal with this issue?thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not converting the inputs to numbers. This means that any "number" that starts with `'6'` is greater than any "number" that starts with `'2'`, even for values like `'6.38'` and `'198.86'`.

```
thisKey, thisSale = data_mapped
thisSale = float(thisSale)
```

Next, you are setting `oldSale` to `0`, but never referring to it. I think you meant to do `maxSale = 0` there, to reset the value for a new store.

Lastly, you don't need `oldKey = thisKey;` in the `if` block, as you're doing that immediately afterward anyway.

Note that currency calculations work best when you convert the values to the smallest denomination of that currency and use integers, as floating-point calculations aren't always perfectly accurate and you may get rounding errors. It looks like your data aren't guaranteed to have trailing zeros, so you would have to check the string for a decimal point, split on the decimal point if it exists, and so on.

```
thisKey, thisSale = data_mapped
if '.' not in thisSale:
    thisSale = int(thisSale)*100
else:
    dollars, cents = thisSale.split('.')
    if len(cents) < 2:
        cents += '0'
    thisSale = int(dollars)*100 + int(cents)
```

Carry out financial calculations on the integer representing the number of cents, and then format values as dollars and cents when necessary for display purposes:

```
>>> '%.2f' % (29886/100.)
'298.86'
>>> '{:.02f}'.format(29886/100.)
'298.86'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

maxsale = 0
oldKey = None
# Loop around the data
# It will be in the format key\tval
# Where key is the store name, val is the sale amount
#
# All the sales for a particular store will be presented,
# then the key will change and we'll be dealing with the next store
d = dict() 
for line in sys.stdin:
    data_mapped = line.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data_mapped) != 2:
        # Something has gone wrong. Skip this line.
        continue

    key,value = data_mapped
    if (key in d) and d[key] < float(value):
        d[key] = float(value)
    elif not key in d:
        d[key] = float(value)

for k,v in d.items():
    print k,'\t',v
```